# Date difference in timestamp and normal dates in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table that has 2 date columns, one is the timestamp value(eg 1359380165) and the other in normal datetime value (eg. 2013-01-28 08:32:53).

I want to find the time lapse between now (Current) and these dates listed above. So the results will be eg.

1. Daniel changed his password 5mins ago
2. Jeniffer deleted her phone number 3days ago.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should do something similar to what you're after, give it a try, it just needs a unix timestamp passed to it like your '1359380165' one.

```
function getRelativeTime($timestamp)
{
    $timeDifference = time() - $timestamp;
    $timePeriods    = array('second', 'minute', 'hour', 'day', 'week','month', 'years', 'decade');
    $timeLengths    = array('60', '60', '24', '7', '4.35', '12', '10');

    if ($timeDifference > 0)
    {
            $timeSuffix = 'ago';
    }
    else
    {
        $timeDifference = -$timeDifference;
        $timeSuffix     = 'to go';
    }

    for($i = 0; $timeDifference >= $timeLengths[$i]; $i++)
    {
        $timeDifference/= $timeLengths[$i];
        $timeDifference = round($timeDifference);
    }

    if($timeDifference != 1) $timePeriods[$i].= 's';

    return $timeDifference . ' ' . $timePeriods[$i] . ' ' . $timeSuffix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a table like this:

### mytable

```
id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key
username varchar(45) not null
utime int
dtime timestamp
```

Why not just structure the query so that PHP receives both timestamps in the same format?  Something like this:

```
SELECT id, username, FROM_UNIXTIME(utime, '%Y-%m-%d %H.%i.%s') AS ut, dtime AS dt FROM mytable;
```

or

```
SELECT id, username, utime AS ut, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dtime) as dt FROM mytable;
```

Then you can process both ut and dt the same way.

There is a nice relative time function [here](http://www.nirojsapkota.com.np/2012/02/get-relative-time-in-php_25.html). It takes a unix timestamp.